# JavaFX/CSS Display an svg shape on the right side of a combo box list cell

Tags: java, css, svg, javafx, fxml

I'm looking to create a combo box whom selected item should set its text bold and display a tick at the right side of the list cell (the tick icon is a SVG):

[image]

Currently in my code the tick takes all the available space:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
.combo-box {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color:     #44494F
    -fx-border-width:     1px
}

.combo-box .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-shape: -arrow;
}

.combo-box:showing .arrow {
    -fx-rotate: 180;
}

.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-font-size: 10px;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: #2F353D;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #2F353D;
    -fx-border-width:     0px
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover{
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-shape:       "m184.405 461.013-184.405-184.405 24.354-24.354 160.051 160.051 332.279-332.279 24.354 24.354z";
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #393E44;
}
```

Is there a way to put the tick on the right side using only CSS ? Even if not, how to achieve that ?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153790/how-can-i-make-a-region-equal-to-another-in-javafx/69184517#69184517) for information on sizing shaped regions.

Comment: I’m not sure what code you are using for this, you should supply a [mcve], not only the css, as the css in isolation isn’t all that helpful for solving the problem.

Comment: You could supply a [custom cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/combo-box.htm) to render the cells (see the priority combo box example).  You could use a layout pane (e.g. HBox) to render the custom cell or perhaps just a Label with a graphic for the tick and an appropriate content display and alignment setting.

Comment: the css in the question doesn't even load, throwing load errors from several lines - not surprisingly, giving it a closer look ;) Note that it __must__ be the exact (partial) css that produces the combo in the screenshots, best as part of a [mcve] as already noted by @jewelsea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jewelsea suggested in the comments, you can supply a custom `CellFactory` to handle the size:

```
ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();

cb.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>() {
        @Override 
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item != null ? item : null);
        }
    };
    Region icon = new Region();
    icon.getStyleClass().add("icon");
    
    cell.setGraphic(icon);
    cell.setGraphicTextGap(20);
    return cell;
});
```

You can set the size and style in `css`:

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell .icon {
    -fx-min-width: 10;
    -fx-pref-width: 10;
    -fx-max-width: 10;
    
    -fx-min-height: 10;
    -fx-pref-height: 10;
    -fx-max-height: 10;
    
    -fx-shape: "m184.405 461.013-184.405-184.405 24.354-24.354 160.051 160.051 332.279-332.279 24.354 24.354z";
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-content-display: text-only;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-content-display: right;
}
```

Output:

[image: ComboBox]

Comment: What does ``if (item != null) {setText(item); } else { setText(null); }`` do?

Comment: Sets de text in the `ListCell` when there is an `item`, otherwise, it clears the text setting it `null`.

Comment: So the same as ``setText( item )``

Comment: In this specific example yes because `item` is a `String`, otherwise you have to extract the value.

Comment: beware: you _must not_ share a node across parents (as you do in the snippet, by using the same icon instance for all cells)

Comment: btw: there is no need to manage the visual update of selected visuals by code - selected is a styleable property of every cell, so we can use seperate rules for un/selected which differ by content-display (text-only/right, respectively). Still need a custom cell, though (default nulls the graphic)

Comment: As noted by @kleopatra, there is no need to manage the visual update of the selected cell by code. I updated the answer to incorporate this.

Comment: what I meant is slightly different: a) in code, only have the ListCell with the icon as graphic (as you do) and _do not_ touch the contentDisplay related properties at all b) in css, define a rule for the cell: `.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell { -fx-content-display: text-only; }` and a second rule for its selected state: `.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:selected { -fx-content-display: right ; }`

Comment: As suggested by @kleopatra, I updated the answer to set the *content-display* in `css`. Btw, @kleopatra is there any performance gain by setting this property in `css`?

Comment: performance is unrelated to css - and to clarify my earlier comments: there's nothing wrong with solving the requirement in code or an arbitrary mixture of code/css. Just assumed from the question _Is there a way to put the tick on the right side using only CSS_ the OP wanted to solve as much as possible by css. Which here would involve also setting the textGraphic gap in css .. just saying :)

Comment: I guess my reading comprehension freezes on weekends ;)